# I can't move a div with percentage

Tags: css, html, percentage

I want to move a div to the bottom but it doesnt move if i write in percentage,but in   pixels it works.

Here's the css:

```
 <style type="text/css">
  html
 {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
   }
  div#container
   {
position:relative;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:left; 
  }
  #g_image3
  {
  width: 100%;
  }
  body {text-align:center;margin:0}
   </style>`
```

Here's the html:

```
 <body bgColor="#000000">
 <div id="container">
  <div id="g_image3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:0px; z-   
 index:1"><img src="images/top_bg.jpg" alt="" title="" border=0 width="100%"   
 heigth="100%"></div>
  <div id="g_image4" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top: 10%;       
  width:265px; height:400px; z-index:1"><img src="images/content1.png" alt="" title=""   
  border=0 width=265 height=400></div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

[Here is a link with the picture of a page](http://imageshack.us/f/690/snapshot20130607214258.png/)

I want to move g_image4 in the bottom, but it keeps remain
clinging of the g_image3 if i write it in percentage.In pixels it works but i need it in percentage nto in pixels.
Where do i mistake?I dont get it why it dont move....

Comment: Please make your code more readable and consider including a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I don't know why you have CSS and you have inline styles too.. Just go on with any of them.. using both will make you confused about which of them actually is being applied. Use !important if you want to give an attribute priority on another one

Comment: well i deleted the css but still it dont move.

Answer (score 1):

You have set a `height: 100%` on the `html` element but neglected to do so on the `body` and `#container` elements. This results in the `body` and `#container` elements having a height of `0`, as there is no static or relative-positioned content in them to give them a height.

Comment: i have set a height of 100% on body too but still dont work...
    body {text-align:center;margin:0;height:100%;width:100%;}

Comment: And on `#container` like I said?

Comment: Oh i didnt saw that.Yeah now it works perfectly.Thank you very much.